# Crashed: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.ios.exception

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, unity-game-engine, crashlytics

I am currently developing a Unity3D game and have integrated the Firebase Crashlytics package into my project. To accommodate the Skillz SDK, which requires an older version of the Firebase package (specifically version 8.9.0), I have made the necessary adjustments.

The problem I'm facing occurs when I build the game for iOS using Unity Editor and subsequently process it through Xcode for testing and deployment via TestFlight. Initially, the game runs smoothly on iOS devices (iPhone) for a few sessions. However, after some sessions, it crashes unexpectedly.

To investigate the issue, I checked the Firebase console, which provided the following crash report:

```
Crashed: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.ios.exception
0  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1c314 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 184
1  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x1c6f4 FIRCLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 1176
2  FirebaseCrashlytics            0x14688 FIRCLSHandler + 48
3  FirebaseCrashlytics            0xf5c0 __FIRCLSExceptionRecord_block_invoke + 92
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x3eac _dispatch_client_callout + 20
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x13428 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
6  FirebaseCrashlytics            0xee40 FIRCLSExceptionRecord + 204
7  FirebaseCrashlytics            0xebec FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 744
8  libc++abi.dylib                0x10fbc std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
9  libc++abi.dylib                0x10f60 std::terminate() + 56
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x33d04 objc_terminate + 16
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3ec0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x126a4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 928
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x122f4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 44
14 CoreFoundation                 0x98c28 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
15 CoreFoundation                 0x7a560 __CFRunLoopRun + 1992
16 CoreFoundation                 0x7f3ec CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
17 GraphicsServices               0x135c GSEventRunModal + 164
18 UIKitCore                      0x39cf58 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
19 UIKitCore                      0x39cbbc UIApplicationMain + 340
20 UnityFramework                 0x140c0 -[UnityFramework runUIApplicationMainWithArgc:argv:] + 96 (main.mm:96)
21 App Name                     0x6908 main + 27 (main.mm:27)
22 ???                            0x1c9cb4dec (Missing)
```

I would greatly appreciate any insights or solutions regarding this problem. Thank you for your assistance

I have tried removing and adding firebase sdk. But crash issue was not fixed.

Comment: To be clear, Crashlytics being in the callstack appears to just be reporting a call that happens in an earlier frame (`11 libdispatch.dylib              0x3ec0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40`) 

A question: are there any exceptions or issues you run into when running it repeatedly from the Unity Editor?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have run the game repeatedly (more than 16 times) from the Unity Editor, and I haven't encountered any issues or exceptions. Perhaps I can continue running the game more times to see if any issues or exceptions arise in the Unity Editor.

Comment: Does it occur when run in the simulator from xcode? If so are there any errors that show up in the log there?

Comment: The ios build is not running in Xcode simulator. It is giving following error

'ld: library not found for -lGameAssembly'
'clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'

Comment: Just to confirm: This error occurs but your builds finish and are runnable on device? Alternatively are you saying this error occurs when you try to build for simulator and that is why you aren't using it?


To investigate the error: Check the build log, expand the transcript with the error, and click the details icon to see the error message. Post it here too if there's interesting info and its not self-evident.

Comment: The error "ld: library not found for -lGameAssembly" and "clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" occurs only when the target SDK is selected as the Simulator SDK in Unity Editor Player Settings. When we select the device SDK as the target SDK, the game builds properly in Xcode without any errors, and we can test it in a sandbox TestFlight on the iPhone. I will check the build log and try to find a solution to the issue. Thank you for your assistance, Joe.